# Troubleshoot reportlab heisenbug

Tags: python, django, pdf, reportlab

Using Django 1.4 / Python 2.7 / reportlab (open source version) to generate pdf.

Things have worked really great up until now. Previously pdf generation (as in http requested returned/downloaded generated pdf file) was on Django 1.3 and not open for public. Have upgraded and made feature free on many pages and now starting to have problems.

I get 'random' problems (as in I see there are exceptions once in a while in logs) but I have never been able to reproduce problems myself (things works most of the time).

What I get is the following type of errors that always happens in pairs

```
    Exception Value: ParaParser instance has no attribute '_seq'
    Exception Location: /home/tss/lib/python2.7/reportlab-2.5-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/reportlab/platypus/paraparser.py in _complete_parse, line 1061
```

and then

```
    Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'
    Exception Location: /home/tss/lib/python2.7/reportlab-2.5-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/reportlab/lib/xmllib.py in close, line 521
```

Given that I am having a hard time reproducing this and not sure if problem on my side or reportlab - I am open for suggestions on how to troubleshoot this (could it be sync issue as in many generating conccurently or just a plain bug or...)???

Answer (score 2):

Posted this question on the reportlab mailing list and Reportlab is not thread-safe.

So any usage of reportlab where you end up getting intermittent problems and are running in a multithread / web app environment you will get really really strange problems due to this.

Now I need to work out what to replace reportlab with, hmm....

/ Jens

Comment: Any progress on that? Did you try `pycairo`?

Comment: Still using Reportlab, talked to them directly and ended up doing a reset of their config in each view prior to generating pdf reports and this has solved things:    rl_config._reset()

Comment: Does it have any side effects? If it is not thread safe, does that influence PDF files that started generating earlier (but still did not finish)?

Comment: Not sure, did fix my issues. Understood it as there are some global variables that are used and this sets them to default.